# How can I repair marred veneer polish?

Tags: wood

I have PU polish on veneer in my wardrobe. I accidently put a heavy weight over it, so polish seems to have left the veneer and appears as white. How can i fix it? Will using hot iron work? Kindly suggest

Comment: A picture would help

Answer (score 3):

No, heat will usually mar it further.  I've had some success in simply buffing the white discoloration with a soft cloth.  I have a terry bathrobe that has be relegated to rag status that I use.